# show that r is repeated root for characteristic equation iff

Tags: linear-algebra

> $A: B \rightarrow B$ a linear operator
>
> Show $r$ is multiple root for characteristic equation $u(x)$ iff
>
> $$\{0\}\subset \ker(A - rI) \subset \ker(A - rI)^2$$

My thought:

I know $\ker(A-rI)$ is basically $\{\{0\}\text{ and }\{\text{eigenvectors associated with } r\}\}$.

what is $\ker((A-rI))^2)$ with respect to above and/or $r$? How is eigevector of $(A-rI)^2$ related to that of $(A-rI)$?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably $A$ is the same as $L$, and $\subset$ denotes a proper subset.  But the statement is not true.  For example, $0$ is a double root of the characteristic polynomial
of $\pmatrix{0 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr}$, but $\ker(L) = \ker(L^2)$.  It would be true for the minimal polynomial instead of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: you are correct. they're both the same (fixed now), it is indeed a proper subset, and it was meant to be minimal polynomial. how do you show it works out?